# Why the facebook login session return authoirization exception?

Tags: android, facebook, session, android-facebook

There are two problem in my facebook session handling,

1) if the user click on accept permission, it return Facebook access token invalid with message “session does not match current stored session”

2) if I press home button during the dialog is shown, I can not press the login button but it show when I press the back button

is the implementation flow correct? (should I remove the session after fail?)

Thanks for helping

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements LoginListener {
    private final static String TAG = "Home";
    public View rootView;
    public ImageView HomeBg;
    public ImageView buttonLoginLogout;
    public TextView chi;
    public TextView eng;
    public ColorStateList oldColor;
    public SharedPreferences prefs;
    public EasyTracker tracker = null;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public ArrayList<String> permission;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    public Home ctx;

    //Facebook login
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        ctx = this;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());

        permission = new ArrayList<String>();
        permission.add("email");

        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("userInfo", 0);
        editor = prefs.edit();

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        buttonLoginLogout = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_connectFB);

        //Facebook login
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(getActivity(), null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(getActivity());
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(permission).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

       updateView();
       return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
        tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "hk7app/CX/" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()) + "/Landing Page");
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
        EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity()).activityStop(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void updateView() {
        Log.d(TAG,"updateView");
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (user != null) {
                            if (!user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))) {
                                editor.putString("fbId", user.getId());
                                editor.putString("fName", user.getFirstName());
                                editor.putString("lName", user.getLastName());
                                editor.putString("email", user.asMap().get("email").toString());
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                            if (prefs.getString("memId","").equals("") || prefs.getString("token","").equals("") || !user.getId().equals(prefs.getString("fbId",""))){
                                pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info),getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
                                new APIHandler(getActivity(),tracker,"login").execute(ctx,session.getAccessToken()); // my backend
                            } else {
                                onLoginComplete("","");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });               
        } else {
            buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_connect_facebook);
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","Fbconnect","connectFB_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setPermissions(permission).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG,"SessionStatusCallback");
            Log.d(TAG,""+exception);
            if (exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sys_info))
                .setMessage(R.string.facebook_permission_missing)
                .setPositiveButton(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.close), null)
                .show();
            } else if (exception == null) {
                updateView();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(getActivity(),getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginComplete(String memberId, String token) {    
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        if (!memberId.equals("") && !token.equals("")) {
            editor.putString("memId", memberId);
            editor.putString("token", token);
            editor.commit();
        }

        buttonLoginLogout.setImageResource(R.drawable.landing_btn_take_a_selfie);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("menu_click","TakeSelfie","Selfie_now_" + Utility.getLocale(getActivity()),null).build());
                ((LandingPage)getActivity()).tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginFailure(String errorMsg) {
        if (pd != null)
            pd.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the built-in `Facebook`SDK login button which enables you to login and get `accessToken` in an easy way

include this XML in your layout

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/authButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    />
```

and follow this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/)

Comment: Are there any way to customized the button?

Comment: Can you tell me what you are going to do? and why you need to custimize it ?